# Stop frames from resizing in respect to the content (Tkinter + Python2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to make something like this using frames:
[image]

And this is my code so far: # I am trying to put the frames in the certain location only, and not fill the entire display

```
from Tkinter import * 

class Menu():
    def display(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(width=1200,height=700)
        self.canvas.grid()

        self.controlcanvas = Canvas(self.canvas,width=850,height=200)
        self.controlcanvas.place(x=348,y=107)
        indexframe = Frame(self.controlcanvas)
        titleframe = Frame(self.controlcanvas)
        readCframe = Frame(self.controlcanvas)
        commentCframe = Frame(self.controlcanvas)

        indexframe.pack(side=LEFT)
        titleframe.pack(side=LEFT)
        readCframe.pack(side=LEFT)
        commentCframe.pack(side=LEFT)

        dummyindex = Label(indexframe,text="#").grid(row=0,column=0)
        dummytitle = Label(titleframe,text="Title").grid(row=0,column=1)
        dummyreadC = Label(readCframe,text="Read Count").grid(row=0,column=2)
        dummycommentC = Label(commentCframe,text="Comments").grid(row=0,column=3)

        mainloop()

m = Menu()
m.display()
```

The problem here is that the `#` `Title` `Read Count` and `Comments` resize the frame into small one.

I want the frames to retain their original geometry so that I could create something like the picture.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

`Frame` has a list of config options that handle its properties like size and border. When you create the frame, you can specify these options:

```
indexframe = Frame(self.controlcanvas, height=400, width=200, borderwidth=2)
```

or you can access them later via:

```
indexframe.config(borderwidth=2)
```

Take a look at the [method documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm#Tkinter.Frame.config-method) for more options.